# RegEx for ICQ UIN

Tags: c#, .net, regex, icq

What `RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression` should I use to allow only ICQ UIN like input?

```
xxx-xxx-xxx and xxx-xxx-xx and xx-xxx-xxx and xxxxxxxxx so on..
```

i.e. with dash as separator and without.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following simple expression.

```
^([0-9]-?){7,8}[0-9]$
```

The drawback is, that it allows things like `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8`. If you want to restrict the layout more, you can use complexer expressions.

```
^(?=([0-9]-?){8,9})([0-9]{2,3}-?)*(?<!-)$
```

This expression asserts that the string contains exactly eight or nine numbers and some dashes using the positive look ahead assertion `(?=([0-9]-?){8})`. Then it matches groups of two or three numbers optionaly separated by dashes and finally asserts that the string does not end with a dash using the negative look behind assertion `(?<!-)`.

This still allows some irregular patterns like `12-34567-89`. If you want to eliminate them, too, you will have to list all allowed patterns. But I suggest not to do so, but allow as much flexibility as possible - I would allow every string with eight or nine numbers and any number of dashes - even `--123---4-5-67--8` and then reformt the user input in a predefined format.

```
^(-*[0-9]-*){8,9}$
```

Comment: Some comments: (1) when I used ICQ, I had a 6-digit number; (2) I think ICQ numbers cannot start with 0; (3) Just ignore the dashes is a nice policy IMHO: `^-*[1-9][0-9-]*$` would be enough...

Comment: Massa, you're giving away your internet age with this...  My ICQ also has a 6-digit number, and I joined 11 or 12 years ago.